# How to get from input datalist selected id

Tags: jquery

Hello i have one datalist and some input with list. i can`t get input selected id

I try do it but it`s not work

```
$(".updateResolutions").click(function () {
      let regDate = $(this).closest('div').find('#regDate').val();                  
      var opt = $('.Organizations option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
      console.log(opt.attr('id'));
            console.log(opt);        
            );
        });
```

this is html

```
<datalist id="OrganizationsList">   
    <option id="1" value="Name1" />
    <option id="2" value="Name2" />      
</datalist>

<div class="col-md-11 borderDiv"> 
        <input type="date" name="regdate" id="regDate" />
        <label for="regdate"> Организация : </label>
        <input type="text" list="OrganizationsList" name="resOrg" class="resOrgId Organizations" value="@item.OrgName" style="width:30em" />
        <button type="button" id="updateResolutions" class="btn btn-default updateResolutions">изменить</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-11 borderDiv"> 
        <input type="date" name="regdate" id="regDate" />
        <label for="regdate"> Организация : </label>
        <input type="text" list="OrganizationsList" name="resOrg" class="resOrgId Organizations" value="@item.OrgName" style="width:30em" />
        <button type="button" id="updateResolutions" class="btn btn-default updateResolutions">изменить</button>
</div>
```

div can be more than 2 (3-10)

Comment: 1. Замени все **id** в **div**'ax на **классы**, иначе у тебя не будут работать другие кнопки, кроме первой. 2. Даталист работать должен как селект или наоборот, **div** должны работать как селекты Даталиста? ----- 1. Change everywhere **id**'s on **class**'es, cause you will get data from the first id everytime. 2. `Datalist` should works as `select` or `div`'s should get `id` of `datalist` via its `value`'s?

Comment: **You cannot have multiple identical id values. id must be unique at all times.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get selected option by its value: `$('#OrganizationsList option[value="' + $(this).siblings('input[name=resOrg]').val() + '"]')`.

```js
$(function(){
    $(".updateResolutions").click(function (e) {                  
        var opt = $('#OrganizationsList option[value="' + $(this).siblings('input[name=resOrg]').val() + '"]').attr('id');
        console.log(opt);
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<datalist id="OrganizationsList">
    <option id="1" value="Name1" />
    <option id="2" value="Name2" />
</datalist>

<div class="col-md-11 borderDiv">
    <label for="regdate1"> Организация : </label>
    <input type="text" list="OrganizationsList" name="resOrg" id="" value="Name1" style="width:30em" />
    <button type="button" id="regdate1" class="btn btn-default updateResolutions">изменить</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-11 borderDiv"> 
    <label for="regdate2"> Организация : </label>
    <input type="text" list="OrganizationsList" name="resOrg" id="" value="Name2" style="width:30em" />
    <button type="button" id="regdate2" class="btn btn-default updateResolutions">изменить</button>
</div>
```

Additionally, the `id` value should be unique in your buttons and other inputs.

Comment: id **must** be unique. Also in your code the labels are no longer attached to the input elements. Empty id attributes are also not legal.

Answer (score 0):

you have few mistakes in your code

id should be unique as i see in you are code resOrgId are used twice

you have extra  ); at JS

the code below should work fine for you

```js
$('.updateResolutions').click(function(){
let regDate = $(this).closest('div').find('#regDate').val();
alert(regDate)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<datalist id="OrganizationsList">   
    <option id="1" value="Name1" />
    <option id="2" value="Name2" />      
</datalist>

<div class="col-md-11 borderDiv"> 
        <input type="date" name="regdate" id="regDate" />
        <label for="regdate"> Организация : </label>
        <input type="text" list="OrganizationsList" name="resOrg" id="resOrgId" value="@item.OrgName" style="width:30em" />
        <button type="button" id="updateResolutions" class="btn btn-default updateResolutions">изменить</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-11 borderDiv"> 
        <input type="date" name="regdate" id="regDate" />
        <label for="regdate"> Организация : </label>
        <input type="text" list="OrganizationsList" name="resOrg" id="resOrgId" value="@item.OrgName" style="width:30em" />
        <button type="button" id="updateResolutions" class="btn btn-default updateResolutions">изменить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: but i need id from input datalist

Comment: @RamazanovAdilbek since id OrganizationsList are used only one time is fine if you are using same id name more than one time is issue, your problem is with ID: resOrgId because is used twice there you should change to class